# Cancel PC ShutDown using shutdown.exe cmd C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using this command in a WinForms app to shutdown my PC:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s");`

at which point Windows 8 and 8.1 displays a message telling me that my PC will shutdown in 1 minute. With no option to cancel.

How can I then (within that 1 minute) send a command to cmd/shutdown.exe to *cancel shutting down the PC*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try shutdown /a

The /a command should abort the shutdown if it's sent within the time limit.

Check out Technet's documentation on Shutdown: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use *pinvoke* to cancel the shutdown (calling `CancelShutdown` in `user32.dll`), rather than invoking another process.

See: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CancelShutdown.html

This is equivalent to what `shutdown /a` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate and abort system shutdowns via P/Invokes to `advapi32`.  See [`InitiateSystemShutdownEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`AbortSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376630(v=vs.85).aspx).  Initiating and cancelling system shutdowns both require `SeShutdownPrivilege` to shut down the computer locally, or `SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege` to shut down the computer over the network.

The complete code should look like the below when privileges are taken into account.  Note: this assumes use of the `System.Security.AccessControl.Privelege` class, which [was released in an MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163823.aspx), available for download [as linked from the article](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/e/9/2e9bde04-3af1-4814-9f1e-733f732369a3/TokenPrivileges.exe).

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdownEx(
    string lpMachineName,
    string lpMessage,
    uint dwTimeout,
    bool bForceAppsClosed,
    bool bRebootAfterShutdown,
    uint dwReason);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool AbortSystemShutdown(string lpMachineName);

public static void Shutdown()
{
    Privilege.RunWithPrivilege(Privilege.Shutdown, true, (_) =>
    {
        if (!NativeMethods.InitiateSystemShutdownEx(null /* this computer */,
            "My application really needs to restart",
            30 /* seconds */, true /* force shutdown */,
            true /* restart */, 0x4001 /* application: unplanned maintenance */))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }, null);
}

public static void CancelShutdown()
{
    Privilege.RunWithPrivilege(Privilege.Shutdown, true, (_) =>
    {
        if (!NativeMethods.AbortSystemShutdown(null /* this computer */))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }, null);
}
```